# OpenCV Python error: Unsupported data type (=4) in function 'cv::opt_AVX2::getMorphologyRowFilter'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to remove noise with morphology and the kernel is giving me errors:

```
import skimage.io as io
import numpy as np
import cv2

c=io.imread('circles.png').astype('bool')*1
x=np.random.random_sample(c.shape)
c[np.nonzero(x>0.95)]= 0
c[np.nonzero(x<=0.05)] = 1

opening = cv2.morphologyEx(c, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((2,2),np.uint8))

io.imshow(opening)
```

error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:/projects/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/morph.simd.hpp:756: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Unsupported data type (=4) in function 'cv::opt_AVX2::getMorphologyRowFilter'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your data type (=4) is CV_32SC1, which is 32-bit signed single channel -- you need to convert your data into another data type, I'd recommend using CV_8UC1 because of the smallest memory footprint and ease of use:

```
c = c.astype('uint8') # or c.astype(np.byte)
```